# what is the ie filter if any for css3 skew

Tags: internet-explorer, css, filter

I have at the moment

```
 -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) skewX(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(-45deg,0deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg) skewX(-45deg) ;
  transform:rotate(-45deg) skewX(-45deg) ;
```

and for the rotate I have so far for ltie8

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678,sizingMethod='auto expand');
```

is there a filter for skewX(-45deg) for ie7 or ie8?

thanks in advance!

I have downloaded a fine jquery plugin from github.com/heygrady/transform But would prefer just the filter in an ie only style sheet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the following from the **CSS3 Transforms Translator** when I added this `rotate(-45deg) skewX(-45deg)`.

More here: http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

```
 /*
 * The following two rules are for IE only and
 * should be wrapped in conditional comments.
 * The -ms-filter rule should be on one line 
 * and always *before* the filter rule if
 * used in the same rule.
 */

#transformedObject {

   /* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.7071067811865483, M12=0, M21=-0.7071067811865467, M22=1.4142135623730934, SizingMethod='auto expand')";

   /* IE6 and 7 */ 
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
            M11=0.7071067811865483,
            M12=0,
            M21=-0.7071067811865467,
            M22=1.4142135623730934,
            SizingMethod='auto expand');


   /*
    * To make the transform-origin be the middle of
    * the object.    Note: These numbers
    * are approximations.  For more accurate results,
    * use Internet Explorer with this tool.
    */
   margin-left: 29px; 
   margin-top: -96px;

}
```