# jQuery 1px lined overlay

Tags: jquery, math

Just wondering if I can do this:

I will have an image that has an overlay top and bottom that is slanted to make the image appear to run up in an angle.

I would then like to run a function that adds 1px high white lines evenly spaced out (about 8px) the entire length of the image, like a sort of screen.

So the first line would run right across the width of the image 8px from the top, then the next 16px from the top and so on.

Any pointing in the right direction would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an image of a mock-up of what you want to do?

Comment: Hope this works

![Image screenshot](http://geoffboult.co.uk/stackoverflow/horizontal-mask.jpg).

The orange BG will actually be an image which has a top slant triange and bottom one overlayed on top so as to make the image under look cropped, then on top of that the horizontal lines.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 Transforms `skewY()` method. [This](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) is a current support in the browsers. And you can write a small script that would create a 1px high `div` with a white background every 8px.

But if know what image (or images) will be used, you should probably just skew them and add those lines using some image processing software (like Photoshop) and use them in your website like that. Or if you don't know which images will be used, but you know the size, you should make an image with those white lines (transparent background PNG) and put it on top of the slanted image.

Comment: Hi Zem, 

I really wanted to avoid using an image overlay to get this effect, we have no idea on the sizes of the images and the project is responsive too so didn't want to have small devices download a big png. 

Surely there is a calculation that jQuery can do to first find the height of the flexible img containing div, then every 8px place a horizontal 1px div over the top, maybe append this to a div that is being overlayed with nothing in. I also need to support IE8 and skew is not.

Comment: As I said in the answer, it's easy to calculate and add these 1px divs using jQuery. Your question was if it's possible, and the answer is "yes". As for the skewing in IE8, take a look at this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824358/what-is-the-ie-filter-if-any-for-css3-skew